# C++ NULL pointers and const correctness

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, const-correctness

I read that it is good practice to do a check in the destructors of classes after deletion for pointer data members as follows:

```
if( 0 != m_pPointer)
{
    delete m_pPointer;
    m_pPointer= 0;
}
```

However, I found out that this prevents you to declare const pointers as data members as follows:

```
Type* const m_pPointer;
```

Isn't assigning `NULL` to pointers(as in my example above) a barrier for const-correctness?
What is the best way to do? Keep everything `const` and stop assigning `NULL` to the deleted pointer or declaring `non-const` pointers even though their address never changes?

Comment: I'd disagree that it's a good practice. Double-deleting a pointer is almost always a logic bug in your application, and setting the pointer to null after deletion hides that bug. If you don't set it to null, the app will probably crash, which is a good thing.

Comment: Do you have a use-case where setting the pointer to `0` actually helps with anything? I've seen this pattern before, but I can't see it helping unless you export references the pointer.

Comment: @JohannesD But where is the `double-deleting`? Assinging NULL to a pointer isn't releasing the memory. `If you don't set it to null, the app will probably crash, which is a good thing` - setting it to null will also crash toe app, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JohannesD everything is in the "probably"... Setting it to null will **ensure** that the program crash when the pointer is used (not on delete that's true). Not setting it to null will not ensure anything.

Comment: @JasonSwartz Again, how could the app "crash"? Do you have an example?

Comment: @JasonSwartz try `delete 0;`, you'll see that is does not crash.

Comment: @JasonSwartz no it won't crash on deleting a `null` pointer. `delete p;` where `p` is null is defined by the language as a no-op. See [`operator delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) for more info on that.

Comment: @juanchopanza See my previous comment. Whenever you set a pointer to `nullptr` every further attempt to use it will crash. That's a good thing for debug. If you don't set it to `nullptr` it may, or may not, crash.

Comment: On entering the block, the object stops existing anyway, so `delete m_Pointer;` is enough. (also `delete` checks for `NULL`) Also, consider use of smart pointers, vectors, strings to make use of Rule of Zero.

Comment: @Johan & WhozCraig Not deleting a NULL pointer but calling a member function(for example) from a null pointer. Here no one's deleting null pointers(first you delete it and second you assign NULL to it) :-?

Comment: The question is asking how to use the wrong tool in the least wrong way. Why aren't you using smart pointers?

Comment: @JasonSwartz: if the pointer isn't shared, and it's only `delete`d in the destructor, yes, it's very hard to accidentally cause a double delete. On the other hand, if that is the case, it makes no sense to make the code more complicated by resetting the pointer to `null` -- we're in the destructor and the pointer is never seen after that! (except maybe in a case of heap/stack corruption)

Comment: You should _keep everything `const` and STOP assigning to `0`._ Reason: Aforementioned by @JohannesD

Comment: @JohannesD Except when you keep a reference on your otherwise dead instance... Seen a lot of time in legacy code here.

Comment: @johan the point is, how can you delete it after the destructor? It is not that easy. It is possible, but it requires some pathologically bad design.

Comment: @milleniumbug `also delete checks for NULL` AFAIK this is not true

Comment: @juanchopanza easy, call delete twice on the same object and your destructor will be called twice... Pathological design is what other do to your code. You have to ensure that it is easy for them to find the bug they created.

Comment: @Johan calling delete twice on the same object is UB anyway. It doesn't help if that object has a pointer set to `nullptr` or not.

Comment: @juanchopanza Not on the destructor, but on the other accesor it will crash as soon as used.

Comment: @Johan: If you try to delete the same object through multiple pointers, you're screwed anyway. Setting just one of the pointers to null isn't going to help. If you have references (or pointers) to the pointer itself, then setting it to null will hide a double delete, but that's just pathological.

Comment: @JasonSwartz *"AFAIK this is not true"* - Then AFAYK is not far enough.

Comment: @JohannesD No it helps because the next call to a function using that pointer will crash... I stated it twice or thrice but it seems that we do not agree :) And it's not purely abstract it is what I encounter daily in badly designed code I have to survive in. Setting to null helps.

Comment: @JasonSwartz Actually, it is! http://parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/delete-handles-null.html

Comment: @JasonSwartz Taken from the C++ standard on `operator delete`: "Default behavior: If ptr is null, does nothing. Otherwise, reclaims the storage allocated by the earlier call to operator new."

Comment: @Johan: There will be no more calls that can access that pointer because the object containing the pointer is destructed! Yes, if it's set to null during the object lifetime, it will both cause subsequent non-delete accesses to it to fail noisily (which is a good thing) and hide subsequent double deletions (which is a bad thing), but in this case it cannot be accessed ever again, so setting it to any value is pointless.

Comment: @JohannesD Even if an object is destructed, if another object holds a pointer on it (aka dangling pointer and ownership problem) you **can** call the method and acces it... That's the whole dangling pointer problem. And yes it is a design flaw, but if you can secure your code against this, I think it is worth the price of a nullptr assign

Comment: @Johan This applies iff you have exporter a *reference* to the pointer, and someone else is holding a *reference* to said pointer. *If* you do that in your class, *then* you might consider setting the pointer to `nullptr`, but even then it is not clear cut. In any other situation, I cannot see any reason one would even consider setting to `nullptr` in the destructor.

Comment: @Johan: Do you understand that if you have two pointers to an object, and set one of them to null, it has no effect whatsoever on the other pointer? If you do `int* foo = new int; int* bar = foo; delete foo; foo = 0; *bar = 42;`, then the `bar` pointer will still point to the now-deleted memory, its value has not magically changed to null!

Comment: @JohannesD Yes, I know. :) The problem is more in wrongly designed program structure a bit like http://ideone.com/cLdXfc , where owership is lost (here it is really simplified :) ). But I cannot make a decent example that would crash with nullptr and not without. It is because the runtime write over my memory in those examples. Maybe this render the nullptr useless in a destructor ? Are we guaranteed that memory will be erased by RT after a destructor call ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is bad practice for the following reasons:

1. Setting a pointer to null in the destructor may mask double destruction problem. Good practise is to detect problems as early as possible.
2. Checking a pointer for null before `delete`ing it only adds unnecessary code. `delete` handles null pointers by doing nothing. Good practice is to minimize the amount of code.

Comment: Agreed. The `if` check goes wasted and is an unnecessary burden.

Comment: So is or is not ok to have constructions like `delete m_pPointer; m_pPointer= 0;` in our code? Assigning NULL to a pointer guarantees that if something is later called on that pointer the program will crash. Isn't it this a good thing?

Comment: @JasonSwartz Are you going to show the example of how it is possible to call something on that pointer later? If you manage to do that, you will see it is quite contrived, and a poor design. And you would just be shifting the problem elsewhere anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza Again, the goal of setting to null is to detect early that there is poor design... If everybody codes perfectly it is not needed. Alas it is not the case.

Comment: By the way, it is what is done in the STL for vector at least (Visual studio 10)... pointers are set to NULL and everything is cleaned.

Comment: Is it that I don't understand or your comments are contradictory?
`Are you going to show the example of how it is possible to call something on that pointer later?` so you're saying that this won't happen in good designed software. `the goal of setting to null is to detect early that there is poor design` so setting to null is actually a good thing?... so is it a good or a bad thing setting a pointer to null? i'm sorry but i'm a bit confused

Comment: @JasonSwartz There is no good reason to use plain pointers for owned resources.

Comment: @JasonSwartz Please note the context: Setting a pointer to null _in the destructor_ may mask double destruction problem.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a null pointer is guaranteed safe, so that null check is pointless.

If a class has a member that is a const pointer to a non-const object then you're saying the pointer value WILL NOT change within the lifetime of the wrapping object - that being the case you should only do this in the case where the object pointed to will live as long or longer than the wrapping object and the wrapping object will never want to point to a different object.

The fact that you have this issue simply means you've used a const pointer in the wrong place.  You claim that in your case the pointer value never changes, but in your example it obviously does - it changes to null.

Comment: The point of the question is whether the value *should* change to null. And the answer to that is, no, it should not, and it should be const.

Comment: Possibly, in your real world case, which cannot be derived from the snippet.  That said, when a member pointer is deleted and reassigned multiple times in a wrapper object's lifetime it *can* be a fair strategy to always ensure the pointer either points to an object or to null, then re-creation of the object can simply `delete` then `new`.  If the object pointed to is instantiated in the initialiser list and destroyed in the destructor, then there's no need to set it to null and it can be a const pointer - or even better just put it on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

A weird situation can be caused when you link a static lib with a global or static object from two different shared libs (on Linux) which later be linked to the same executable.

Each shared lib object insert call to constructor and destructor, so you'll have one object and two calls for constructor and destructor for the same object (actually you'll have 2 objects mapped to the same address).

You'll probably find the problem when your app crash in the 2nd destructor. 
if you NULL it you'll never know that there was a problem at all.

for your question: except for the above issue, I think you should distinct two types of pointers: 
See the class below:

```
class A{
  obj *x, *y;
  A(){
    x = new obj;
    y = NULL
  }
  ~A(){
    delete x;
    if(y)delete y; // the `if` here will save the calling and returning run time when NULL. 
  }
  void RecicleX(){
    delete x;
    x = new obj;
  }
  void InitY(){
    assert(y==NULL); //illegal to call init when already
    y = new obj;
  }
  void TermY(){
    assert(y); //illegal to call term when already inited
    delete y;
    y = NULL; //prevent crush in dtor if called after...
  } 
};
```

x is always exists, so no need to check it, and no need to null it. y may exists and may not, so I think you should null it after deletion. 
(You maybe will want also to know the current state, like for `assert`)

Answer (score 1):

The "best way to do" is:

```
class foo {
  std::unique_ptr<bar> m_pPointer;
public:
  foo(std::unique_ptr<bar> pPointer)
    : m_pPointer{std::move(pPointer)} {}
};
```

or for const,

```
class foo {
  const std::unique_ptr<bar> m_pPointer;
public:
  foo(std::unique_ptr<bar> pPointer)
   : m_pPointer{std::move(pPointer)} {}
};
```

No `new`, no `delete`, no destructor.